# how to change color of mat-icon in input in angular 6?

Tags: css, angular, input, icons

this is my html file :

```
      <div class="input-field">
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="name" required email/>
      <label for="name">Email:
        <mat-icon svgIcon="mail" class="change-color"></mat-icon>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="psw" required />
      <label for="psw">Password:</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

this is my css file :

```
.input-field {
position: absolute;
width: 302px;
height: 44px;
line-height: 20px;
}

label {
position: relative;
top: -25px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
color: rgba(158, 158, 158, 1.0);
transition: 0.2s all;
cursor: text;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 400;
}

input {
width: 100%;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
padding: 0.5rem 0;
border-bottom: 2px solid #d3d3d3;
box-shadow: none;
color: #111;
}

.change-color {
color: #787878;
height: 12px;
width: 12px;
float: right;
}


input:invalid {
outline: 0;
}

input:focus,
input:valid {
border-color: #00dd22;
}

input:focus ~ label,
input:valid ~ label {
font-size: 14px;
top: -45px;
color: #00dd22;
mat-icon.change-color{
color: #00dd22;
height: 12px;
width: 12px;
float: right;
 }
}
```

Now I want to change the color of the icon when I click on the input but icon does not move. i solve this problem by add css like this:

```
input:focus ~ label,
input:valid ~ label {
font-size: 14px;
top: -45px;
color: #00dd22;
mat-icon.change-color{
color: #00dd22;
height: 12px;
width: 12px;
float: right;
 }
}
```

But still, the icon moves while its color changes,
i made sample here but here this css:

```
 input:focus ~ label,
input:valid ~ label {
font-size: 14px;
top: -45px;
color: #00dd22;
mat-icon.change-color{
color: #00dd22;
height: 12px;
width: 12px;
float: right;
 }
}
```

But this code does not work here ☝☝: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dgrpcx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html, so I created an example of another way

how i can solve it ?
i using angular 6 .

this is image of what i want http://prntscr.com/m12bb0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS, add:

```
input:focus ~ label.ee .change-color {
  color: #00dd22;
}
```

[Here is a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ccpg3s).

Comment: color of icon changed this is good, but I do not want the icon to be moved.

Comment: See the [Angular Material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#form-field-appearance-variants) for a good use of suffix icons. You should use `<mat-icon matSuffix>` inside a `<mat-form-field>`.

Comment: thanks i found my answer Where you said
https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#form-field-appearance-variants

Comment: just one thing. how i can use API in this site for example change color of input when clicked I would appreciate if you can explain with an example.

Comment: There are 4 pre-built themes for Angular Material that you can use and override but you can also use your own theme, everything is described [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming).

Comment: If you just need a little change, you can override it in CSS but if you need to change all the colors, you should use a [custom theme](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-custom-theme) *(with Sass)*.